# How can I detect and remove unneeded points in cubic bezier

Tags: svg, bezier

Here is example image of what I want to do:
[image]

I want to calculate **Path 1** from **Path 2**.

Screenshot made from Inkscape, where I'm, at first, create **Path 1**, then add **p3** to the original path. This is didn't change the original path at all, because new point actually unneeded. So, how can I detect this point(p3) using **Path 2** SVG path representation and calculate **Path 1** from **Path 2**?

Basically, I search for the math formulas, which can help me to convert(also checking that whether it is possible):
`C 200,300 300,250 400,250 C 500,250 600,300 600,400`
to
`C 200,200 600,200 600,400`

Comment: little confused about your path data, since that second path instruction in the compound curve doesn't correspond what you showed; it doesn't end on (600,400), it ends on (600,580)

Comment: It because there is two path in one document, so Path1 is under Path2.  I just copy Path2 and move it down, so that's why Y coordinate is different. My mistake.  
Correct paths are:  
`C 200,200 600,200 600,400`  
and  
`C 200,300 300,250 400,250 C 500,250 600,300 600,400`

Comment: please update your post with that correct information

Comment: Update path and picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're solving a constraint problem. Taking your first compound curve, and using four explicit coordinates for each subcurve, we have:

```
points1 = point[8];
points2 = point[4];
```

with the following correspondences:

```
points1[0] == points2[0];
points1[7] == points2[3];

direction(points1[0],points1[1]) == direction(points2[0], points2[1]);
direction(points1[6],points1[7]) == direction(points2[2], points2[3]);
```

we also have a constraint on the relative placement for points2[1] and points2[2] due to the tangent of the center point in your compound curve:

```
direction(points1[2],points[4]) == direction(points2[1],points2[2]);
```

and lastly, we have a general constraint on where on- and off-curve points can be for cubic curves if we want the curve to pass through a point, which is described over at http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#moulding

Taking the "abc" ratio from that section, we can check whether your compound curve parameters fit a cubic curve: if we construct a new cubic curve with points

```
A = points1[0];
B = points1[3];
C = points1[7];
```

with B at t=0.5 (in this case), then we can verify whether the resulting curve fits the constraints that must hold for this to be a legal simplification.

The main problem here is that we, in general, don't know whether the "in between start and end" point should fall on t=0.5, or whether it's a different t value. The easiest solution is to see how far that point is along the total curve (using arc length: distance = arclength(c1) / arclength(c1)+arclength(c2) will tell us) and use that as initial guess for t, iterating outward on either side for a few values.

The second option is to solve a generic cubic equation for the tangent vector at your "in between" point. We form a cubic curve with points

```
points3 = [ points1[0], points1[1], points1[6], points1[7] ];
```

and then solve its derivative equations to find one or more t values that have the same tangent direction (but not magnitude!) as our in-between point. Once we have those (and we might have more than 2), we evaluate whether we can create a curve through our three points of interest with the middle point set to each of those found t values. Either one or zero of the found t values will yield a legal curve. If we have one: perfect, we found a simplification. If we find none, then the compound curve cannot be simplified into a single cubic curve.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. I see 'A Primer on Bézier Curves' before, but it's too complicated for me now, not my level.
In my case, I have just a two curveto and I don't know where there middle point is. So, could I check is this compound curve can be simplified using several formulas or it's more complicated task?

Comment: Except for the fact that there is no "just" in what you want to do. What you want is a mathematically hard problem, which can be simplified by using the formulae from the article in the linked section. If you need demonstration code to work off of, hit the view-source button and then "steal" the code from the BezierComputer class. Also note that the primer is not "not my level", it's just what it is. If you want to work directly on, rather than just with, Bezier curves, you picked a hard subject and you'll need to put in a bit of work =)

Comment: I see... Thanks anyway. I'll try to go deeper in your article, trying to understand all of this Bézier magic.